# sprocket file oclazyLoad not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower

I am using bower rails gem

```
gem "bower-rails" #, "~> 0.9.0"
```

On my Bowerfile

```
asset 'oclazyload'
```

This produces a bower.json file with

```
"ocLazyLoad": "latest"
```

Then I require the module

```
//= require oclazyLoad
```

This works on localhost but when I deploy I am getting an error.

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'oclazyLoad' with type 'application/javascript'
```

Comment: Are you using Rails 5 ?

Comment: No I am using rails 4.2